# react router not getting route after click

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-routing

My `routes.js` is something like:

```js
const routes =  (
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/one" component={One} />
        <Route path="/two" component={Two} />
  </Route>
)
export default routes
```

I have a header file in `App` component and my header file looks like:

```js
class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3><Link to={`/one`}>One</Link></h3>
        <h3><Link to={`/two`}>Two</Link></h3>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Header
```

When I run `localhost:3333` it goes to the `App` page that containse `Header` with `One` and `Two`. But when I click on that, it is not displaying the content or component of `One` and `Two`.

What am I missing in the router?

Need help.

Comment: where is your `this.props.children`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me guess you missed `this.props.children`. So your component should look like

```
class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3><Link to={`/one`}>One</Link></h3>
        <h3><Link to={`/two`}>Two</Link></h3>
        <div>{this.props.children}</div> // this is the way how React renders different components based on route 
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Header
```

[React-Route](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/latest/docs/guides/basics/RouteConfiguration.md) link for more information.
I hope it will help you.

Thanks